# How do I clean messages in the queue if producer is down

Tags: activemq-classic

I'm using ActiveMQ and I would like to know how to solve this specific case.

When the consumer is down, the producer sends a message to the queue. The message will remain in the queue until the consumer is running to consume it.

Now imagine I shutdown the producer, the message will STILL remain in the queue. Now i run the consumer and it will try to consume that message, but won't be able to reply back to the producer since its down.

I would like to solve this problem by cleaning the messages if the producer is out. 
The ActiveMQ Broker cleans the Queue after stopping. I would like to do the same for the messages of a respective producer.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not an ActiveMQ user so I can't really say something useful about this specific scenario, but I want to point out the often-overlooked possibility of [setting a time to live on messages produced by each MessageProducer](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/products/products/jms/javadoc-102a/javax/jms/MessageProducer.html#setTimeToLive%28long%29).  Using this feature properly can considerably mitigate the problem you are describing.

Comment: I also want to point out that [setJMSExpiration()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/jms/Message.html#setJMSExpiration%28long%29) from `Message` may superficially seem to do the same, [but won't work as expected](http://activemq.2283324.n4.nabble.com/Difference-setJMSExpiration-setTimeToLive-td2360498.html)

Comment: yeah but by setting an expiration to the messages wouldn't solve the case. Imagine you set a TTL to the message of 20 seconds. And the producer is shutdown before the 20 seconds, i want that message to be removed like in the same time the producer was shutdown and not wait the remaining time. In that remaining time the consumer might consume it and for example do a money charge to the client and no way to reply back that the client was charged since its shutdown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on what I understand now from your question and additional comments I propose to add a [Message Property](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/bncev/index.html) to your messages to identify the Producer, and write a small utility that uses a [Message Selector](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/bncer/index.html) to read all messages matching the Producer from the queue.  You can run that utility straight after the Producer is stopped (or crashes), and that should quite accurately do what you want to achieve.

EDIT: although primarily focused on EE, the [Sun/Oracle JavaEE Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnceh.html) contains a very good chapter on general JMS programming that starts off with standalone producers and consumers.  The accompanying source code bundle can be downloaded [here](https://java.net/projects/javaeetutorial/downloads), the ready to comoile samples in that bundle should get you started very quickly.

Comment: Mmmmm that would be a nice approach, happens that i dont know how to implement it yet, need to think about it :) thanks!

Comment: thanks, end up using Topic instead of Queue with a Selector on consumer side. I dont know why im getting 2 consumer responses... like its passing through the consumer twice. Still need to figure that out.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve it a couple of ways.  One is to set a TTL on the message so it goes away.  The other is to connect via JMX and purge the Queue or remove the specific message using a selector statement or with the Message's specific MessageId value.

See this [article](http://www.consulting-notes.com/2010/08/monitoring-and-managing-activemq-with.html) for some hints.

Comment: Thanks. What's TTL ? (Time-To-Live) ? btw, im working this with Mule. So i would need to set this from Mule or from the activemq.xml file. Going to keep checking :)

Comment: @TimBish see my comments above - setting expiration via Message **does not work**, you **have** to set TTL on the Producer.

Comment: Yea but, imagine you set a TTL to the message of 20 seconds. And the producer is shutdown before the 20 seconds, i want that message to be removed like in the same time the producer was shutdown and not wait the remaining time. In that remaining time the consumer might consume it and for example do a $$ charge to the client and no way to reply back that the client was charged. There might be some kind of Strategy or Policy for that :/

Comment: I've added a Message Property Transformer applying "timeToLive" as a key and "5000" as a value (in msecs) in the producer. So basically i shutdown the consumer and send messages to the queue with the producer. The messages are "Enqueued" and "Dequeued" after 5 seconds instead of going to a DLQ. Is that correct?